# Add audio on html

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the HTML code that to run the "Wheel of Fortune Bingo".
I want to add audio when the wheel is spinning and the music should auto stop if there is no spinning.
Please advise on this.

Below here is the HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wheel of Fortune Bingo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    text{
        font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        pointer-events:none;
    }
    #chart{
        position:absolute;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    #question{
        position: absolute;
        width:400px;
        height:500px;
        top:0;
        left:520px;
    }
    #question h1{
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        top:50%;
        -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);
                transform:translate(0,-50%);
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="question"><h1></h1></div>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var padding = {top:20, right:40, bottom:0, left:0},
            w = 500 - padding.left - padding.right,
            h = 500 - padding.top  - padding.bottom,
            r = Math.min(w, h)/2,
            rotation = 0,
            oldrotation = 0,
            picked = 100000,
            oldpick = [],
            color = d3.scale.category20();//category20c()
            //randomNumbers = getRandomNumbers();

        //http://osric.com/bingo-card-generator/?title=HTML+and+CSS+BINGO!&words=padding%2Cfont-family%2Ccolor%2Cfont-weight%2Cfont-size%2Cbackground-color%2Cnesting%2Cbottom%2Csans-serif%2Cperiod%2Cpound+sign%2C%EF%B9%A4body%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4ul%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4h1%EF%B9%A5%2Cmargin%2C%3C++%3E%2C{+}%2C%EF%B9%A4p%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4!DOCTYPE+html%EF%B9%A5%2C%EF%B9%A4head%EF%B9%A5%2Ccolon%2C%EF%B9%A4style%EF%B9%A5%2C.html%2CHTML%2CCSS%2CJavaScript%2Cborder&freespace=true&freespaceValue=Web+Design+Master&freespaceRandom=false&width=5&height=5&number=35#results

        var data = [
                    {"label":"Winner 1",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for specifying the area between the content and its border?"}, // padding
                    {"label":"Winner 2",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the font?"}, //font-family
                    {"label":"Winner 3",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the color of text?"}, //color
                    {"label":"Winner 4",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the boldness of text?"}, //font-weight
                    {"label":"Winner 5",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the size of text?"}, //font-size
                    {"label":"Winner 6",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the background color of a box?"}, //background-color
                    {"label":"Winner 7",  "value":1,  "question":"Which word is used for specifying an HTML tag that is inside another tag?"}, //nesting
                    {"label":"Winner 8",  "value":1,  "question":"Which side of the box is the third number in: margin:1px 1px 1px 1px; ?"}, //bottom
                    {"label":"Winner 9",  "value":1,  "question":"What are the fonts that don't have serifs at the ends of letters called?"}, //sans-serif
                    {"label":"Winner 10", "value":1, "question":"With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify a class?"}, //period
                    {"label":"Winner 11", "value":1, "question":"With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify an ID?"}, //pound sign
                    {"label":"Winner 12", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag holds all of the content people see?"}, //<body>
                    {"label":"Winner 13", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag indicates an unordered list?"}, //<ul>
                    {"label":"Winner 14", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag indicates the most important heading of your document?"}, //<h1>
                    {"label":"Winner 15", "value":1, "question":"What CSS property is used for specifying the area outside a box?"}, //margin
                    {"label":"Winner 16", "value":1, "question":"What type of bracket is used for HTML tags?"}, //< >
                    {"label":"Winner 17", "value":1, "question":"What type of bracket is used for CSS rules?"}, // { }
                    {"label":"Winner 18", "value":1, "question":"Which HTML tag is used for specifying a paragraph?"}, //<p>
                    {"label":"Winner 19", "value":1, "question":"What should always be the very first line of code in your HTML?"}, //<!DOCTYPE html>
                    {"label":"Winner 20", "value":1, "question":"What HTML tag holds all of the metadata tags for your page?"}, //<head>
                    {"label":"Winner 21", "value":1, "question":"In CSS, what character separates a property from a value?"}, // colon
                    {"label":"Winner 22", "value":1, "question":"What HTML tag holds all of your CSS code?"}, // <style>
                    {"label":"Winner 23", "value":1, "question":"What file extension should you use for your web pages?"}, // .html
                    {"label":"Winner 24", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for marking up content and structure on a web page?"}, // HTML
                    {"label":"Winner 25", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for specifying the design of a web page?"}, // CSS
                    {"label":"Winner 26", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for adding functionality to a web page?"}, // JavaScript
                    {"label":"Winner 27", "value":1, "question":"What CSS property is used for making the edges of a box visible?"}, // border
                    {"label":"Winner 28", "value":1, "question":"What character symbol is used at the end of each CSS statement?"},//semi-colon
                    {"label":"Winner 29", "value":1, "question":"By default, how wide is a <div> box?"}, //100%
                    {"label":"Winner 30", "value":1, "question":"What character symbol do I use to specify multiple CSS selectors in one code block?"},
                    {"label":"Winner 31", "value":1, "question":"What character symbol do I use to specify multiple CSS selectors in one code block?"}                  //comma
        ];


        var svg = d3.select('#chart')
            .append("svg")
            .data([data])
            .attr("width",  w + padding.left + padding.right)
            .attr("height", h + padding.top + padding.bottom);

        var container = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "chartholder")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2 + padding.left) + "," + (h/2 + padding.top) + ")");

        var vis = container
            .append("g");

        var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d){return 1;});

        // declare an arc generator function
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

        // select paths, use arc generator to draw
        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "slice");


        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i){ return color(i); })
            .attr("d", function (d) { return arc(d); });

        // add the text
        arcs.append("text").attr("transform", function(d){
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = r;
                d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle)/2;
                return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.outerRadius -10) +")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .text( function(d, i) {
                return data[i].label;
            });

        container.on("click", spin);


        function spin(d){

            container.on("click", null);

            //all slices have been seen, all done
            console.log("OldPick: " + oldpick.length, "Data length: " + data.length);
            if(oldpick.length == data.length){
                console.log("done");
                container.on("click", null);
                return;
            }

            var  ps       = 360/data.length,
                 pieslice = Math.round(1440/data.length),
                 rng      = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1440) + 360);

            rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);

            picked = Math.round(data.length - (rotation % 360)/ps);
            picked = picked >= data.length ? (picked % data.length) : picked;


            if(oldpick.indexOf(picked) !== -1){
                d3.select(this).call(spin);
                return;
            } else {
                oldpick.push(picked);
            }

            rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps/2);

            vis.transition()
                .duration(3000)
                .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
                .each("end", function(){

                    //mark question as seen
                    d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path")
                        .attr("fill", "#111");

                    //populate question
                    d3.select("#question h1")
                        .text(data[picked].question);

                    oldrotation = rotation;

                    container.on("click", spin);
                });
        }

        //make arrow
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w + padding.left + padding.right) + "," + ((h/2)+padding.top) + ")")
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M-" + (r*.15) + ",0L0," + (r*.05) + "L0,-" + (r*.05) + "Z")
            .style({"fill":"black"});

        //draw spin circle
        container.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 0)
            .attr("cy", 0)
            .attr("r", 60)
            .style({"fill":"white","cursor":"pointer"});

        //spin text
        container.append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("SPIN")
            .style({"font-weight":"bold", "font-size":"30px"});


        function rotTween(to) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(oldrotation % 360, rotation);
          return function(t) {
            return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
          };
        }


        function getRandomNumbers(){
            var array = new Uint16Array(1000);
            var scale = d3.scale.linear().range([360, 1440]).domain([0, 100000]);

            if(window.hasOwnProperty("crypto") && typeof window.crypto.getRandomValues === "function"){
                window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
                console.log("works");
            } else {
                //no support for crypto, get crappy random numbers
                for(var i=0; i < 1000; i++){
                    array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + 1;
                }
            }

            return array;
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an advice forum. Please show us what have you tried to get the audio working.

Comment: Downvoting for pasting entire document source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JS directly without touching the dom

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
// wheel is spinning
audio.play();
// wheel is not spinning
audio.stop();
```

[HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) allow to control from JS audio file nativelly.

In alternative you could use some JS libraries as:

https://howlerjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your expertise advise.

Comment: @eagleeagle I hope my answer helped you out with your question. IF you found it useful, please do not forget to accept it or up vote it by clicking the "tick" or up arrow on its left side. Thanks.

Comment: @Gibook, Noted with thanks.
I did the last code which is : 
// wheel is not spinning
audio.stop(); 
I have to put audio.pause(); 
Otherwise, the wheel will only work 1 time

Comment: @eagleeagle thanks for your comment :) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Setup an `audio` tag to the source of your `audio` like this.

```
<audio controls loop>
    <source src="/path/to/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

**Then in your script add this initially.**

```
var audioElement = document.getElementById('audio');
audioElement.pause();
```

**Then play the audio when spin has started.**

```
function spin(d) {
    audioElement.play();
   //....
}
```

**Finally pause when spin has stopped.**

```
vis.trainsition()...
.each("end",function() {
    //,....
    audioElement.pause();
});
```

Read more about audio tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).

Comment: thanks for the advise,
still got some issues on this and I'm trying to fix this.